# How to insert value from an array into an other array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
a = [a_first_element, a_second_element, a_third_element, a_fourth_element]
b = [b_first_element, b_second_element, b_third_element, b_fourth_element]
```

I would like to insert in the first array, at even positions, elements of the second array.

So the final array shoud look like :

```
[a_first_element, b_first_element, a_second_element, b_second_element, a_third_element,b_third_element, etc]
```

The arrays are made of the same number of items (around 30)

How could I do that ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to `zip` the arrays together.  Doing this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [111, 222, 333, 444]
c = a.zip(b)
```

will set `c` to:

```
[[1, 111], [2, 222], [3, 333], [4, 444]]
```

which is *almost* what you want, but you probably don't want the nested arrays.  To get rid of the nested arrays, just call `flatten`:

```
c = a.zip(b).flatten()
```

Now `c` is set to:

```
[1, 111, 2, 222, 3, 333, 4, 444]
```